# OIDC filter for legacy servlet application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid-connect

I would like to intercept request to a legacy Java servlet/JSP application, and authenticate users with the OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol.

I have seen examples with Spring Security and SAML where the `springSecurityFilterChain` was configured explicitly in XML and wrapped existing non-Spring servlets.  But most of the Java OIDC examples I've seen have been with Spring Boot, which is not an option for me. (for example: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/18/spring-security-5-oidc)

Can you point me at any non-Spring Boot examples that use OIDC clients in Java webapps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/) and specifically the combination of `j2e-pac4j` and `pac4j-oidc` were the easiest way to plug OIDC into a plain-old-servlet application.

[`j2e-pac4j`](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j) is implemented as a vanilla Java servlet filter (actually two, because you need a callback handler) that plug into `web.xml` to intercept requests. These filters reference a Java class that you provide to configure the OIDC client.

Okta's developer blog has an [article on using pac4j-oidc with Play framework](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/31/add-authentication-to-play-framework-with-oidc) and this seems like a reasonable way to go for Java as well, given that Spring Security feels too complex or hard to set up inside a legacy app.